# dpkg --dry-run option is not simulating installation properly

Tags: software-installation, raspbian, dpkg, dependencies

Given a random .DEB file, how do we check if installation will be successfully completed without actually installation on device? Please see the following snippet:

```
root@VirtualBox:/Folder# dpkg -i mysql-workbench_6.2.3+dfsg-7_armhf.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench.
(Reading database ... 48937 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench_6.2.3+dfsg-7_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench (6.2.3+dfsg-7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench:
 mysql-workbench depends on libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1); however:
  Package libatkmm-1.6-1 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.14.0); however:
  Package libcairo2 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench depends on libcairomm-1.0-1 (>= 1.6.4); however:
  Package libcairomm-1.0-1 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench depends on libctemplate2; however:
  Package libctemplate2 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench depends on libgdal1h (>= 1.8.0); however:
  Package libgdal1h is not installed.
 mysql-workbench depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not installed.
  Package libgl1 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench depends on libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.42.0); however:
  Package libglibmm-2.4-1c2a is not installed.
 mysql-workbench depends on libgnome-keyring0 (>= 2.22.2); however:
  Package l
dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.3-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench
root@VirtualBox:/Folder# echo $?
1
root@VirtualBox:/Folder# dpkg --dry-run -i mysql-workbench_6.2.3+dfsg-7_armhf.deb 
(Reading database ... 49115 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench_6.2.3+dfsg-7_armhf.deb ...
root@VirtualBox:/Folder# echo $?
0
root@VirtualBox:/Folder# dpkg --dry-run --simulate -i mysql-workbench_6.2.3+dfsg-7_armhf.deb 
(Reading database ... 49115 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench_6.2.3+dfsg-7_armhf.deb ...
root@VirtualBox:/Folder# echo $?
0
root@VirtualBox:/Folder#
```

When I use the `dpkg -i` option, the command fails with a return value of 1, but the same command as a `--dry-run` returns zero. Adding the `--simulate` option also doesn't seem to change behaviour. Any pointers on how to consistently check if installation of a .DEB file will go through properly, without actually installing the package?

I am running this on a Raspberry Pi emulator.

```
root@VirtualBox:/Folder# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: I believe that --simulate is more intended for apt actions, for example, apt-get upgrade --simulate will tell you what packages will be removed, etc. dpkg is a lower level action, which itself often cannot handle the dependencies and other things like that, that is to say, it itself does not actually know the end results of an action. It's unclear to me if you are installing a standard deb from the pool, or if this is a custom deb file you have created yourself, if it's the latter, then apt can't really look at the relevant databases. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure.

Comment: It's a VM.  Take a snapshot, and roll back if it fails.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: Not what I asked.

Comment: @Lizardx: Is there no way that I can do a dry-run for the debian files? I am currently trying this out with standard pool debians, but would want to extend this to custom debian files later on.

Comment: No, I believe you may have a mistaken notion of what --dry-run does. I'm not positive, but I think all it does is examine the apt database, dependencies, etc, then show you what it believes will happen with an install/upgrade. Since you want to find out what will happen with packages that do not exist in the database, and which have no documented relationships to other packages, I don't see how --dry-run etc can possibly work in the way you want it to. Do what Dope said, take a snapshot and test it.

Comment: It's a good question, but I believe it simply devolves to the fact that dpkg --simulate doesn't actually do what you expected it to do. It seems it never has, it's probably outside of the scope of dpkg. I did provide an upvote because it's a good question, and a sort of pseudo-answer. Only reading the dpkg code could provide a real answer.

Comment: I'm glad Stephen Kitt looked into it more. While it's obvious that --simulate and dpkg won't do what the person wanted, it's always interesting poking into the internals of apt and dpkg, which remain as far as I'm concerned the best by far package management system, along with the strict Debian lintian rules, in the GNU/LInux ecosystem. After using these tools as long as I have, you tend to have a sense of what won't work, like dpkg --simulate, so it's something I never even tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To determine whether a package can be installed without needing other dependencies to be installed too, your best bet is to use the “simulate” mode with `apt`:

```
apt -s install ./mysql-workbench_6.2.3+dfsg-7_armhf.deb
```

(note the `./` which is significant). This will output the `dpkg` operations which would be performed by the real installation. Package installations are marked with `Inst`; if there’s more than one of these, the package can’t be installed on its own.

Now, on to the meaty part... You can’t use `dpkg` for this, not because `dpkg` doesn’t know about dependencies (it most definitely does), but because dependencies aren’t strong enough. When a package depends on another, the dependency doesn’t prevent the package from being *installed* if it’s not satisfied, it prevents it from being *configured*. See [section 7.2 of Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#binary-dependencies-depends-recommends-suggests-enhances-pre-depends):

> A `Depends` field takes effect *only* when a package is to be configured. It does not prevent a package being on the system in an unconfigured state while its dependencies are unsatisfied, and it is possible to replace a package whose dependencies are satisfied and which is properly installed with a different version whose dependencies are not and cannot be satisfied; when this is done the depending package will be left unconfigured (since attempts to configure it will give errors) and will not function properly.

You can see this in your own test: the process fails with

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench
```

Note “configuration”, not “installation”. If you look at the output of `dpkg -l mysql-workbench`, you should see `iU`, which means the package is installed but not configured.

When you enable “simulate” mode in `dpkg`, it basically runs in read-only mode. It does this by setting a `f_noact` flag; you can look for this in the source code. When installing packages, simulation goes through the installation motions (without writing anything), and proceeds to the configuration phase; but that [just fakes success](https://git.dpkg.org/cgit/dpkg/dpkg.git/tree/src/configure.c?id=f7e9dc18083d5677a633db108c209675e7602417#n637), which is the only thing that a simulation can do — configuration involves running maintainer scripts in the package, and it would be difficult to ensure that those scripts didn’t make changes, or ensure that their success could be determined without allowing them to make changes. So in your case, the simulation installs the package, which succeeds (as in your non-simulated test), and fakes the configuration. Thus no error is detected...

Comment: I believe there is one more thing, because this error when run as regular user: "dpkg: could not open log '/var/log/dpkg.log': Permission denied". So even  there it's not acting the same as apt-get --simulate, which has no requirements for anything related to root permissions. I'm glad someone looked into the guts of dpkg though to find the actual answer, I've simply never thought to use dpkg  --simulate because it didn't seem like it would or could work, as we see in the above poster's example.

Comment: The log is opened for writing in all cases, which explains the error — logging doesn’t come under the “make no changes” umbrella ;-).

Comment: Yes, that was my point, I think, the --simulate obviously doesn't need logging yet it attempts to do it because it always does it, which points I think to the fact that the --simulate flag isn't really designed to do what the original poster thought it would do. That's sort of a bug in the dpkg man page now that I think of it, the differences should be made clear there, with a better explanation of what --simulate/--dry-run is actually good for, it's actual purpose, that is. Reading just the text of the man item would make most people conclude that it will test the install with dependencies.

Comment: Indeed — the man page is accurate, “Do everything which is supposed to be done, but don't write any changes”, it’s just that most people expect that there’s more that’s supposed to be done than actually is. It’s clear in the `dpkg` maintainer’s mind, as you say it needs to be made clear in the documentation... `dpkg` itself could be improved, *e.g.* in this case it could perhaps check for configurability without running scripts before skipping the configuration phase. (Oh and yes, it shouldn’t need to log...)

Comment: It's funny how difficult it can be at times to get devs to state in clear language what they consider self evident, to themselves, since they know the code, it's evident, but they so often fail to grasp that nobody else shares that state of awareness, and so, language is there ready to help out. Maybe a nudge there might be of use, but I've often been struck by how difficult it is to get someone to explain in clear words the full explanation, particularly so when it's a man page which can be as verbose as you want it to be, in fact, it should be just that verbose, to cover everything.

Comment: This explained a lot. Also the apt alternative you suggested worked much better towards my purpose. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

While this isn't technically an answer, it was a good question.

If we look at man dpkg, this is what it says about the options to test. If any real Debian experts can provide a more authoritative response, that would be good. Or edit mine if it has errors in it.

```
   --no-act, --dry-run, --simulate
          Do everything which is supposed to be done, but don't write any changes. This is used to see what would happen with the specified
          action, without actually modifying anything.
```

I believe, though I'm not certain, that in essence, all dpkg is testing is if the command has any flaws in it. For example, if you did:

```
#dpkg --dry-run -i nonexistent.deb || echo $?
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'nonexistent.deb': No such file or directory
2
```

that's the result. One thing I noted was that dpkg required root even with --dry-run, it complained about not being able to use the log file, which means, `--dry-run` does not do at all what we expect. With `apt-get`, you can use --simulate as regular user.

dpkg is a very low level apt tool, and as you can see from its results in your tests, it did not know about the apt database and dependency trees until it actually installed the .deb file. So I would deduce that `dpkg --dry-run` or `--simulate` etc simply are testing the actual literal command data, not the dependencies etc.

Which suggests that while it appears to be the same command that works pretty decently, but not perfectly, in apt-get, it is in fact not at all the same. One would have to read the code in dpkg --simulate to see what it actually does.

Researching this issue appears to confirm what I believe is the case:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2005-November/013049.html

> > If a feature, is there an automatic way of checking a .deb's
> >     dependencies, other than trying to `dpkg -i` it (and ending up
> >     with under-configured packages) or doing a `dpkg -f` and checking
> >     the dependencies one by one by hand?
> >
> > What I'm looking for is a something like dpkg-buildpackage's
> >     'Unmet build dependencies: ...' check, but for .debs.
>
> There is a new application available called "gdebi" at:
>   http://people.ubuntu.com/~mvo/gdebi/
>
> It should be able to resolve dependencies of deb package directly. It
>   contains gdebi-gtk and gdebi (and cli version). That might be what you
>   want. If not, please let me know and it may be added :) If you
>   use/test it, feedback (via private mail) is very much appreciated.

That's a very old thread, and I'm sure you're not looking for a gui tool, but it is worth noting that the issue existed in 2005 and someone crafted a gui solution that would check dependencies, which suggests that in fact, dpkg --simulate does not. Nor would I expect it to, I have done a lot of automated scripting for Debian apt, and dpkg, and the two act and behave very differently.

**Various options to determine dependencies using dpkg**

https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2006/09/msg00292.html

That's an old Debian thread on the same question, again, you can see that dpkg --dry-run doesn't handle dependencies in general.

https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2006/09/msg00297.html

```
dpkg-deb -I package.deb
```

Is the suggestion there. That shows basically the same thing as `apt-cache show package-name`.

So at least you can verify the dependencies yourself.

```
 dpkg -I perl_5.26.0-8_i386.deb
 ....
 Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.17.17)
 Depends: perl-base (= 5.26.0-8), perl-modules-5.26 (>= 5.26.0-8), libperl5.26 (= 5.26.0-8)
....
```

https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2006/09/msg00312.html

> If you use `dpkg --control pkg_file`, then it will show you all of the
>   control information for the package, including dependencies.

I tested that, but it shows nothing, it may be obsolete, I don't know.

As you can see, Debian devs had several suggestions, but none of them suggested that there was a way to make `dpgk --dry-run` do what you want.

**Conclusion**

You have a few options, one, determine the dependencies manually, and this will certainly apply to your future case of creating your own debs, and then install those dependencies using a scripted install or whatever you find works for you, then install the .deb package after that.

Using the vm is a good option too, with snapshots, for testing.